# Docker - nginx with mounted host volume hangs using docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I'm very new to Docker and I'm having an issue setting up a simple file server. My goal is to link the host volume (Windows) to the guest Linux VM.

The issue is that after running `docker-compose up`, the console hangs with the stdout "Attaching to docker_web_1".

[image: docker-compose up stdout]

I have three main files and one folder, which is the root directory for the server "web", that I need to attach to the Linux VM.

docker-compose.yml:

```
web:
  image: nginx
  volumes:
   - C:/docker/web:/usr/share/nginx/html/
  ports:
   - "8080:80"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
```

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    sendfile on;
    server {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index index.html;
        server_name localhost;
        listen 80;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me set up this server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected, attaching means your console is 'linked' with stdout and stderr of the container.

If you visit `localhost:8080`, you should be able to see logs in your console.

If you don't want the log, use `docker-compose up -d` instead, `-d` means `detached`.